# What makes a webpage's sound continue after the page is closed on iOS in Facebook APP?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, audio

On IPhone 5 when opening link witch contains audio and playing the file, then going back or closing the page - returning to Facebook, but the audio continues playing!

Comment: Can you show an example, ie the link?

Comment: Because the `UIWebView` containing the web-content it is not visible in the view hierarchy but hasn't yet been destroyed?

Comment: Any way to stop the playback? Any chance that any event fires on closing the UIWebView? Tnks alot!